# postgresql retype in index

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, indexing

How can I create index in PostgreSQL like:

```
CREATE INDEX i_users_user_id
ON users
USING btree (user_id::character varying);
```

I want Integer column to behave like String column:

```
SELECT * FROM vw_users WHERE user_id='string'
```

'string' is some value and I don't know if it is user_id or session_id and I want only one query:)

vw_users is:

```
SELECT user_id::character varying FROM users
UNION
SELECT session_id as user_id FROM temp_users
```

Tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE users (user_id integer)
CREATE TABLE temp_users (session_id character varying)
```

Regards

Comment: Side Note : assigning  `varchar` for an _ID_ field is a **BAD** idea

Comment: varchar for id is bad idea, but I have session_id column, it must be varchar. I tried create index, which i wrote, but it was error with message: syntax error at or near "::"

Comment: My next idea is create table etc. `CREATE TABLE users (user_id integer, user_id_chv character varying)` with rule for clone integer column into varchar column, than I can create view and index on varchar columns. But it is my last choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index on an expression requires an extra set of parentheses:

```
CREATE INDEX i_users_user_id
ON users
USING btree ((user_id::character varying));
```